# UI Automation Edge Browser Open/Save Bar

Tags: vba, microsoft-edge, ui-automation

I'm trying to get the following line of code that was working in IE, to work in the Edge Browser: FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)

I need to automate clicking the SAVE button for the Edge Notification Bar question "Do you want to open or save file......" after clicking on a PDF.  I'm using UI to click the SAVE button.

Has the "Frame Notification Bar" class name changed from IE to Edge?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, we recommend you use Selenium WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge. The available language are Java, Python 3, C#, Ruby, and JavaScript. Please refer to [Use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp#automate-microsoft-edge-with-webdriver) for more info.

I created a code sample using C# to download a file automatically without appearing "save" dialog:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System.Threading;

namespace EdgeDriverSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
            try
            {
                driver.Url = "https://example.com/";

                var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#downloads_path"));
                element.Click();
               

                Thread.Sleep(5000); 
               

            }
            finally
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            
        }

    }
}
```